# Testing react app with mock data from external resource

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have been using jest, enzyme and moxios for testing my react app. API responses are stored as mocks in app itself. It has been hard to maintain these mocks as when an api response gets modified, I have to manually update the mock with necessary changes. Also there are other react apps which use the same apis and have mocks in their repository. What is the correct approach to store mocks in an external resource like s3 so that it can be accessed by mutiple apps?

Answer (score 1):

My goal was to load mock data from a mock server while running tests instead of using a hardcoded mock data. I achieved this using [msw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msw). It allows us to intercept http requests and return mock data. Here instead of returning mock data, I made a fetch call to get mock data from a server and returned it as mock response.

Code:

```
import { rest } from 'msw';
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';

const server = setupServer(
  rest.post('/photos', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_limit=1')
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(result => {
        return res(
          ctx.json(result)
        )
      })
  }),
)
```